# Reason why my device failed SafetNet attest API

Tags: android, safetynet

I am working with the `SafetyNet Attest` API and I have tested my app on a number of devices. All the devices were un-rooted devices with their original bootloader. Till now they all passed the attest api test. Currently I am testing it on a Motorola Nexus 6. It is not rooted and the bootloader is the one provided by OEM. But for some reason the device is failing the `ctsProfileMatch` and the `basicIntegrity` check.

A small table is given [here](https://developer.android.com/training/safetynet/attestation.html#compat-check-response) listing why a device might fail, but the output JSON has only the boolean fields and no data on why the device failed.

Any idea on how to fetch the details on why my device failed?

Answer (score 0):

The latest version of the API sometimes includes a string called "advice" in its response, which can be used to show a user-friendly message to help the user pass future attestation checks.

You may want to try to see what this parameter shows for your device.